# comparing drop down options with javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have this form with the following drop down options.
i want a script of some sort, that when a user selects the U18ft from the first box, only the first 4 options are available, and if the pick O18ft the last 3 options are available, and if N/A is selected only wilderness is available.

Or if they select a combination it flags up that is cant be done?

```
<tr>
                <td>Veh Length:</td>
                 <td>
                    <select name="length" id="length">
                        <option value="N/A"> N/A
                        <option value="U18ft"> Under 18ft
                        <option value="O18ft"> Over 18ft
                    </select>
                 </td>
                 <td>Select pitch type:</td>
                 <td>
                    <select name="type" id="type">
                        <option value="Premier"> Premier
                        <option value="Standard"> Standard
                        <option value="Delux"> Delux
                        <option value="Wilderness"> Wilderness
                        <option value="Standard_super"> Super Standard
                        <option value="Delux_super"> Super Delux
                        <option value="Premier_super"> Super Premier
                     </select>
                 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: im not sure where to even start

Comment: Trial and error. Start with learning about the `onchange` event of drop down list and how you can use it in JS. Then you can get the selected value by the `.value` property, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple sample

```js
window.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    //e.target
    if (e.target.id == "length") {
        toggleTypes(e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value);
    }
});

function toggleTypes (lth) {
    var sct = document.getElementById("type");
    var ons = sct.options.length;    
    for (i=0;i<ons;i++) {
        if (lth == "N/A") {
            if (i == 3) {
                sct.options[i].style.display = "inline";
                sct.options.selectedIndex = 3;
         }
            else {
                sct.options[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }        
        else if (lth == "U18ft") {
            if (i < 4) {
                sct.options[i].style.display = "inline";
                sct.options.selectedIndex = 0;
         }
            else {
                sct.options[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        else if (lth == "O18ft") {
            if (i > 3) {
                sct.options[i].style.display = "inline";
                sct.options.selectedIndex = 4;
         }
            else {
                sct.options[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}

toggleTypes("N/A");
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Veh Length:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="length" id="length">
                <option value="N/A"> N/A </option>
                <option value="U18ft"> Under 18ft </option>
                <option value="O18ft"> Over 18ft </option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>Select pitch type:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="type" id="type">
                <option value="Premier"> Premier </option>
                <option value="Standard"> Standard </option>
                <option value="Delux"> Delux </option>
                <option value="Wilderness"> Wilderness </option>
                <option value="Standard_super"> Super Standard </option>
                <option value="Delux_super"> Super Delux </option>
                <option value="Premier_super"> Super Premier </option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach onChange event on  with id="length" and based on its value you can have a switch case that determines the values to be populated in the other drop down.

Sample event handler in Jquery:

```
 $('#length').change(function(){
     var selection= $("#length" ).val();
   //switch case on "selection" variable's value 
});
```

Comment: `$("#length" ).val() === this.value`